# Slow Serialcommunication between Raspberry Pi and Ardunio Mega

Tags: pi-4, arduino, java

I'm in the process of tinkering with something, and for that I need an Arduino to collect measurement data, and a PI to process it all and send it on. My problem is that the connection between my Pi and the Arduino is very slow. I am talking about a latency of up to 20 seconds. It is definitely not the Arduino, because I tried the same program on my PC and it worked very well.

Here is my code on the Pi side:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;

public class Arduino extends Thread {

    SerialPort port;
    public int poti1;
    public boolean connected;

    public Arduino(SerialPort pPort){
        int poti1 = 0;
        this.port = pPort;
        if(port.openPort()) {
            System.out.println("Successfully opened the port.");
            connected = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unable to open the port.");
            connected = false;
            return;
        }
        port.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_SEMI_BLOCKING, 0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        Scanner data = new Scanner(port.getInputStream());
        while(data.hasNextLine()) {
            try{sleep(10);}catch(InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}
            try{poti1 = Integer.parseInt(data.nextLine());}catch(Exception e){}
            System.out.println(poti1);
        }
    }
}
```

And the main class on the side of the pi:

```
import communication.osc.OSCSender;
import communication.usb.Arduino;

public class Main {

    private static OSCSender oscSender;
    private static Arduino arduino;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        arduino = new Arduino(SerialPort.getCommPort("ttyACM0"));
        arduino.start();
    }
}
```

On the Arduino side I use one of the sample programs:

```
/*
  AnalogReadSerial

  Reads an analog input on pin 0, prints the result to the Serial Monitor.
  Graphical representation is available using Serial Plotter (Tools > Serial Plotter menu).
  Attach the center pin of a potentiometer to pin A0, and the outside pins to +5V and ground.

  This example code is in the public domain.

  http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/AnalogReadSerial
*/

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  // read the input on analog pin 0:
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  // print out the value you read:
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  delay(1);        // delay in between reads for stability
}
```

Hope you can Help me

isi_ko

PS: I'm using a Pi 4 and the arduino is conected to a USB 3.0 Port

Comment: Why not change `Serial.begin(9600);` to `Serial.begin(115200);` and add a matching `port.setSerialPortParams(
    115200,
    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);` so that Java runs at the same speed.

Comment: I cant do that, because then my IDE says that its an Error

Comment: http://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/javadoc/com/fazecast/jSerialComm/SerialPort.html#setBaudRate-int- allows you to set the baud rate in your non-standard library.

Comment: even with 9600baud - should not be a delay of 20sec.

Comment: maybe the RPI cannot keep track of the amount of data beeing received. did you try to send in lower frequency?

Comment: you are sending data with 1000times per second.

Comment: another thing could be flow-control. please check that RTS/CTS (hardware handshake) is disabled.